# Managing duplicate class instances in a javascript Set

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, typescript, set

I have a class called `Thing`.  For simplicity, let's say it initializes with a unique id, and that's all that's unique about it:

```js
class Thing {
  id: string;

  constructor(id: string) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

Based on its `id`, a `Thing` will reference a specific item in the underlying database.  It is essentially an abstraction class to help interact with data.

I have a helper class to manage the `Thing`s:

```js
class AllTheThings {
  existingThings: Set<Thing> = new Set();
  createThing(id: string){
    const newThing = new Thing(id)
    this.existingThings.add(newThing)
  }
}
```

Throughout a certain cycle in the code, `createThing` is called with a variety of `id`s.  That cycle repeats, and `createThing` may be called again with the same `id`s from the last cycle.  That is fine.  But at the start of any cycle, I need to have a list of the unique `Thing`s that already have been created in the past.

I need a way to keep a list of unique `Thing`s which have been created so far.  I initially thought of using a `Set`, as above.  However, due to the repetition, and the fact that I am adding a class instance to a set, the entries repeat.  For example:

```
// cycle1:

AllTheThings.createThing(1)
AllTheThings.createThing(2)


// cycle2:

AllTheThings.createThing(2)
AllTheThings.createThing(3)
```

My intention at the end of cycle2 is that I would have 3 unique items in the `existingThings` Set.  But I end up with 4.  For those not familiar with `Set`, this is because `new Thing(1) !== new Thing(1)`.  While the resulting objects are identical, they are not the same, and they point to different references in memory.  I get that.

But the problem remains that I need a list of unique `Thing`s that have been created in the past.  I am considering doing the following:

```
class AllTheThings {
  existingThings: Set<string> = new Set();
  createThing(id: string){
    const newThing = new Thing(id)
    this.existingThings.add(id)
  }
}
```

So in this case, I am keeping a list of unique `id`s, and I won't get the same type of repetition as before.  However, I really need a list of unique `Thing`s, not `Thing` ids.  In reality the code is more complex, and a `new Thing` takes more arguments than just an `id`.  While those arguments are available when calling `createThing`, they may not be available when accessing `existingThings`, which means I cannot easily recreate a `Thing` just from an `id` where `existingThings` is used - I need the whole `Thing`.  I can go the route of using a `Set` of `id`s, but it would require a lot of refactoring.

Is there a more concise way to maintain a list of unique objects/class instances in a `Set`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible workaround could be to use a `Map` rather than a `Set`. That way you can store `Thing`s by their IDs (which we already know uniquely identify them) and then use those IDs to unambiguously get the `Thing` back later

Admittedly, this does carry the risk that the IDs get out of sync and the `Map` ends up associating a `Thing` with the wrong ID, but it doesn't sound like `Thing`s' IDs are meant to change over their lifetimes, in which case it should be safe

Comment: Interesting...I think this is a nice compromise.  I can say `existingThings: Map<string, Thing> = new Map()`, then I can say `this.existingThings.set(newThing.id, newThing)`.  Even when that same Thing is created with the same id, it will call `.set` again, but it won't duplicate, it will just overwrite, which I think will be fine.  I will try this, thank you!